# 'Translating' coded numbers from SQL database based on related text field in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a bunch of coded numbers that represent each county in the United States.  Each county's code is unique, and is made up of a two-digit state code and a three digit odd number based on a county.

For example, in my SQL database, Texas is code 42. Dallas County, Texas is 42113; Dawson County, Texas is 42115.

I am trying to match these codes with another DB table that contains similar codes but with differing state codes.  In this DB, Texas is code 45, so Dallas County is 45113. So, even though I have the correct data, the codes do not match up correctly.

Here is how I'm currently pulling the data.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT county_id,county,state FROM data GROUP BY county_id");
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $county_id          = $row['county_id'];
    $county             = $row['county'];
    $state              = $row['state'];
    array_push($rows,$row);
    printf ("%s,%s,%s\n<br>", $row['county_id'], $row['county'], $row['state']);

}
```

This gives me a coded list of each state in the U.S.

What I need to do is convert each county_id to the correct state code number while leaving the last three digits of each code the same.  I.e., if the value of the string 'state' is TX, then I need to change the '45' in '45113' to '42113.'  If the value of the string 'state' is WV, I want to change the '47' in '47***' to '12***'.

For some reason I just can't wrap my mind around a way to do this efficiently.  Any ideas?

Comment: I can't help it, but -1 for the conditions. How on the Earth you managed to have such inconsistent database?

Comment: I think you need to start from the scratch building your database ...

Comment: The codes in the database are inconsistent because the data comes from two different government agencies that use two completely different set of two-digit state codes. I'm trying to get these to match.

Comment: On the other hand, the question is clearly stated, with expected results.  How/why the database is structured the way it is, that is a different topic/question.

Comment: @BWS unlike the most coding forums, here's not a place where "I have this very problem", "You have this solution"... I, as a user, found here very nice ways, good practices and modern ways of coding, so I came to the conclusion, we are in the place, where we need to teach the users to not use bad practices, bad structures, spaghetties and all the stuff burried in the time.

Comment: @RoyalBg -- I agree 100% with you.  Pointing out bad practice would definately be encouraged.  Marking down the question because of inherited 'bad' code could make users think twice about even asking.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary fix until you can nuke your database from orbit (it's the only way to be sure...) and build a proper one:

```
$county_translations = array(
    'bad_id' => 'new_id'
    ...
);

$fixed_county = $county_translations[$row['county_id']];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my own problem by using substr_replace.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$county_id = $row['county_id'];
$county_count = $row['county_count'];
$state = $row['state'];
if ($state == "AL")
        {
        $county_id_al = substr_replace($county_id,'1',0,1);
        echo $county_id_al;
        echo ",";
        echo $county_count;
        echo "<br>";
        }
```

and so on.  This checks the entry's state, and then removes the first (or first two digits, depending on existing ID codes) and replaces them with the 'correct' one or two digit code.

Those of you who suggested the DB needed to be blown up:  You're right, and I have no clue why they didn't just use the correct FIPS codes to begin with.  But at this point, we've blown waaaaaaaay past the point where changing it makes sense.